# How to implement sound circle wave effect on Android?

Tags: android

I want to do next effects.

1. Some objects.
2. Objects change their position when users beat the objects.
3. There are some circles appear and disappear from the center of the point where users beat the objects.

I tried many things, GL, Path...
My question is which is the best way to implement those effects?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you maybe rephrase? Not sure what exactly is being asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this project from Github

https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

just download try this one!

Comment: You are so great! This is exactly what I want. Love you!╮(￣▽￣)╭